# Transcription feature missing

Tags: google-translate

Earlier Google Translator (web application) also used to transcript the Source text in target language during translation but it is not doing so anymore.
I need that old feature as it served as a good transcription service. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

There are formulas in Google Docs that let you translate text, is that what you're referring to?

See [Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en).

Comment: Please do mention the function ([GOOGLETRANSLATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331)) in your answer. It makes it much more useful.